# Содержит ли строка заданную подстроку?

Tags: javascript

Каким способом можно определить что в строке есть искомый текст?

[<sup>Перевод вопроса "How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?"</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1789945/6275986)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/

Comment: и в чем этот тайный смысл публикации переводов вопросов-ответов, при этом даже без упоминания автора оригинального ответа и ссылки на него? Ладно бы связь такая поддерживалась на уровне СО и репутация оригинальному ответу шла. А так сомнительное начинание с созданием фейковых вопросов.

Comment: @teran, https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/70

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Способов, на самом деле, достаточно много:

1. [**`String#indexOf(str: String[, fromIndex: Number]): Number`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) - один из старейших способов.

   Возвращает найденную позицию `str` или, если подстрока не найдена, `-1`.
   Параметр `fromIndex` определяет отступ поиска.

   **Важно:** В условии необходимо использовать сравнение и обязательно строгое:

   1. Без сравнения, `-1` (отсутствие подстроки) трактуется как `true`.
   2. Может возвращать `0` (совпал первый символ), что приводится обычным сравнением к `false`.

      ```
      'Hello, world!'.indexOf('world'); // 7
      'Hello, world!'.indexOf('o');     // 4, в конце hello
      'Hello, world!'.indexOf('o', 5);  // 8, вторая буква в world
      !!'Hello, world!'.indexOf('z');   // true, отрицательное число приводится к true
      !!'Hello, world!'.indexOf('H');   // false, 0 трактуется как false
      ```
2. [**`String#search([regexp: RegExp]): Number`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) - тот же `String#indexOf`, только с регулярным выражением и отсутствием смещения.

   ```
   "Date of birth of Einstein: 3/14/1879".search(/\d{4}/); // 32
   ```
3. [**`String#includes(searchString: String[, position: Number]): Boolean`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains) - более кошерный вариант `String#indexOf` с двумя отличиями:

   1. Возвращает `Boolean`, вместо позиции, что может быть более ожидаемым.
   2. Работает быстрее. Однако разница ощутима только на весьма больших объёмах, [проверить](https://jsperf.com/str-indexof-vs-str-includes).

      ```
      'Hello, world!'.includes('o');    // true, в конце hello
      'Hello, world!'.includes('o', 9); // false, после девятого символа нет 'o'
      ```
4. [**`String#match(regexp: RegExp): Array | Null`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) - `String#search` на стероидах (однако, медленнее).

   Возвращает немного модифицированный массив с найденной подстрокой, позицией совпадения (`index`) и свойством `input` - строкой, в котором проходил поиск или `Null`, если регулярка ничего не нашла.
   Опционально, в массиве могут быть захваченные группы.
   При использовании флага `g`, вернутся все найденный совпадения (правда без групп и особых свойств):

   ```
   "Date of birth of Einstein: 3/14/1879".match(/(\d{4})/);                       // [0: "1879", 1: "1879", index: 32, input: "Date of birth of Einstein: 3/14/1879", length: 2]
   `Date of birth of Einstein: 3/14/1879;
   Date of birth of Hendrik Lorentz: 7/18/1853`.match(/(\d)\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/g); // [0: "3/14/1879", 1: "7/18/1853", length: 2]
   ```

Есть ещё методы [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) или [`RegExp#exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec), который так же могут быть использованы для проверки, но это уже совсем другая история.

Comment: А почему вы задали вопрос и на него сами же ответили? :D

Comment: @KryTer_NexT, [Можно ли ответить на свой вопрос?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let
  str   = document.getElementById("in1"),
  sub   = document.getElementById("in2"),
  btn   = document.getElementById("btn"),
  res   = document.getElementById("result"),
  val, substr;

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  val     = str.value,
  substr  = sub.value;
  
  res.innerText = val.indexOf(substr) !== -1;
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.contain {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#in2 {
  margin: 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="contain">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Строка" id="in1">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Подстрока" id="in2">
    <button id="btn">Проверить</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]